Get Device name, not a model name
In mobile about phone section there is an option called device name,in which i can able to change the name.i want to get that name programatically,i tried a lot but nothing works.
I tried to get device using Build class, but there is no option to get the customised device name

This question is similar to: How can I get the device name in Android?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
